# Retrieve specific values from a collection in sailsjs model

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

### Merchant.js

```
module.exports = {

attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string',
      required:true
    },
    drinks:{
      collection:'Drinks',
      via:'merchant'
    }
  }
};
```

### Drinks.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string',
      required:true
    },
    category:{
      model:'Category'
    },
    merchant:{
      model:'Merchant'
    }
  }

};
```

### Category.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name:{
      type:'string',
      required:true,
      unique: true
    }
  }
};
```

I want to retrieve the merchant with the drinks associated with the given input category.
Can someone help me in the find query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
var selectedCategory;//given input category.

async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      Drinks
        .find({
          category: selectedCategory
        })
        .exec(function(err, drinks) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          callback(null, drinks);
        });
    },
    function(drinks, callback) {
      Merchant.find({
          drinks: drinks  //In Pairs
        })
        .populate('drinks')
        .exec(function(err, merchants) {
          if (err) return callback(err);
          callback(null, merchants);
        });
    }
  ],
  function(err, results) {
    if (err) return res.badRequest(err);
    res.ok(results);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in the second function I am getting the merchants as blank. Here is the scenario : 
Merchant1-Drinks1(category:VODKA),Drinks2(Category:VODKA),Drinks3(Category:GIN).
Merchant2- Drinks4(category:VODKA),Drinks5(Category:GIN),Drinks6(Category:GIN).
Merchant3- Drinks7(category:RUM),Drinks8(Category:WHISKEY),Drinks9(Category:RUM).

if the input category will be "VODKA", then response should come like :
Merchant1 : Drinks1,Drinks2
Merchant2 : Drinks4

Comment: I think the issue is the "In pairs" search. I think I misunderstood the type of the "drinks", if its an array, you might need to leverage database specific feature like $in for MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

$in also didn't meet my requirement. I didn't find any sails support.
So I changed my logic as in the following :

```
  var selectedCategory = req.param("value");

  async.waterfall([
      function(callback) {
        Category
          .findOne({
            name: selectedCategory
          })
          .exec(function(err, cat) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, cat);
          });
      },
      function(cat,callback) {
        Drinks
          .find({
            category: cat.id
          }).populateAll()
          .exec(function(err, drinks) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, drinks);
          });
      },
      function(drinks, callback) {
        var merchantIds = [];// to store unique merchant ids
        drinks.forEach(function (drink) {
          if (merchantIds.indexOf(drink.merchant.id) < 0) {
            merchantIds.push(drink.merchant.id);
          }
        })
        callback(null, drinks,merchantIds);
      },
      function(drinks,merchantIds, callback) {
        Merchant
          .find({ where: {'id': {"$in": merchantIds}},skip:page*perPage,limit:perPage}).populateAll()
          .exec(function (err, merchantList) {
            if (err) return callback(err);
            callback(null, drinks,merchantList);
          });
      },
      function(drinks,merchantList, callback) {
        var merchantsList = [];
        merchantList.forEach(function (merchant) {
          var merchants={};//to store merchant details in JSON format
          merchants['id'] = merchant.id;
          merchants['name'] = merchant.name;
          merchants['drinks']=[]
          drinks.forEach(function (drink) {
            if (merchant.id===drink.merchant.id) {
              merchants['drinks'].push(drink);
            }
          })
          merchantsList.push(merchants)
        })
        callback(null, merchantsList);

      }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
      if (err) return res.badRequest(err);
      res.json(results);
    });
```